# Hide zoom control in amcharts map v3?

Tags: html, amcharts

I'm using amcharts map V3 and it seems that all the documentation pages for amcharts V3 are broken (like this [one](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/ZoomControl)).

My question: how can I hide the zoom control in the amcharts map and the toggle for hiding and displaying points?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Zoom control and Export icon:

```
  "zoomControl": {
    "panControlEnabled": false,
    "zoomControlEnabled": false,
    "homeButtonEnabled": false
  },      
  "export": {
    "enabled": false
  }
```